# Very Low ICC in HLM

Tags: multiple-regression, nested-data, multilevel-analysis

I ran a HLM analysis (One Way ANOVA with random effects model). I calculated my ICC and it is very small (00.1%). I understand this means that there is basically no meaningful level-2 variability in the level-1 variable.

I have to run an analysis on the data still (it was a hypothesis). Do I still use HLM and just note the low ICC and hence unlikely to find anything of value? I had read before that a significant ICC value means that HLM is warranted. Does this mean that I should use a different analysis (e.g., standard regression)? I am trying to come up with a rationale or explanation if asked a question such as, why did you use HLM with an ICC of 0%?

Comment: Have you tried to ask yourself why the ICC is so small (excluding user mistakes in performing the analysis)? What's your level-1 variable, what are your level-2 units? How many level-2 units do you have?